# Lenovo X201 speaker problems in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, audio

I'm using a X201 Laptop with Mint 18 (Latest Version) with the following problem. I have no sound on the built-in speakers. The sound card driver is working; when I plug in headphones, I have sound. The speakers themselves are working too, and are showing up in the system settings.

I hear the login sound after booting, and the speakers are working for a short period of time (between 1 and 3 minutes) then they just don't work any more. I can't find any errors in the `syslog`.

edit, added output of lspci (looks the same before and after the problem occurs):

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset KT Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci` after the sound stops coming? Also, if you run ALSA text mode mixer `alsamixer` and use F6 to choose the adapter your speakers are attached to, what values are the volume bars at? Any outputs muted?

Comment: Thank you for anwering. I edited the output. When i use the alsamixer there is nothing muted. I found a setting there called "auto-mute" which i disabled and enabled for testing, without any effect.

Comment: So the device is not disappearing, which is good and bad at the same time. What happens if you mute and unmute speaker out? Does the sound come back? Any clicks from the speakers while doing that? If does not help, file a kernel bug and hope they fix it in the new kernels.

Comment: Pressing the Volume buttons in any way doesn't help. I have a docking station. When I plug the laptop in the sound comes back, but from the docking stations integrated speakers. Also when i put the laptop to sleep mode and log back in again, the sounds comes back...

Comment: Likely the kernel module bug. Good luck getting this fixed. My bug reports usually get auto-closed due to end of life, i.e. 3-4 years later, with no one ever looking into them.